When I scroll on a div, the text overflows on div
I have an Issue with this section of my code. I have included the css and the html.


.article-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  overflow: auto;
}

.article,
.article1 {
  width: 560px;
  height: 800px;
  left: 55%;
  z-index: 10000;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 37%;
  background-color: #161D6F;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.article {
  left: 55%;
}

.article1 a {
  color: white;
  overflow: auto;
}

.article1 {
  left: -30%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 900;
  overflow: auto;
}

.article1::before,
.article::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  filter: blur(10px);
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 15%;
  overflow: auto;
  pointer-events: hidden;
}

.article,
.article1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
<h1>Welcome to my Website!</h1>
<div class=article id="dynamicContent">
</div>
<div class=article1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadContent('---.html')">N</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadContent('--.html')">M</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadContent('---.html')">S</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadContent('--.html')">F</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadContent('--.html')">F</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadContent('--.html')">S </a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadContent('---.html')">C</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadContent('--.html')">N </a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadContent('--.html')">M </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>



When I scroll down on Article, the text overflows over the div, with the div not fully covering the text . I was wondering as to what the issue could possible be? I am a beginner in css so my apologies if this is a silly mistake.

Probably because you've set a fixed height for your .article. N.B. height: 900; is invalid

Fix CSS mistakes
After reviewing your css, I would suggest to you to fix the next errors

Set height in pixels correctly for .article1 (as height: 900px; instead of height: 900), as missing px can lead to incorrect height rendering.
Adjust the ::before pseudo-elements to avoid overlapping. You can add overflow: hidden; to the ::before pseudo-elements to prevent them from spilling out visually.

    .article1 {
      left: -30%;
      width: 300px;
      height: 900px; /* Fixed the height unit */
    }
    
    .article1 a {
      color: white;
    }
    
    .article1::before,
    .article::before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: #ccc;
      filter: blur(10px);
      z-index: -1;
      opacity: 0.15;
      overflow: hidden; /* Prevents overflow from pseudo-element */
    }

This is all what I can suggest. If this fixes dont give any result, it would be better to see all your code.
